# Use oauth to connect GAE python application to google's drive/docs/spreadsheet

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, google-drive-api

I'd like to allow my Google App Engine application to connect to a clients Google Spreadsheet on their Google Drive. I've spent the last two and a half days trying, and I've gotten nowhere. Half of the GAE Python documentation seems to be out of date. For example some of the examples have `webapp`, and they don't work until I change them to `webapp2`, but that doesn't always work.

I created a OAuth2.0 thing *(not really sure what to call it)* at:
https://code.google.com/apis/console/

So now I have a Client ID and Client Secret, but one doc talked about a `CONSUMER_KEY` and `CONSUMER_SECRET`. So are they the same or?

I followed the following doc to use OAuth to read my tasks *(I know it's a different API)*, but I couldn't figure out step/Task 3. I'm not sure if I have all of the files/librarys to connect using OAuth. I have the `gdata-2.0.17` files, and I know how to connect to the drive and spreadsheets by hard coding the login credentials, but no user is going to give me their credentials.

I don't normally ask for code, or even help, but I'm completely lost with this whole OAuth API/Service.

If someone could post some sample code that uses OAuth 2.0 and `webapp2`, and that you have tested, that would be awesome.

If someone could link me to a sample GAE Python project that can authenticate with Google's servers and allow it to connect to the users spreadsheets using OAuth 2.0 and webapp2, I'd be over the moon.

Answer (score 4):

A complete example application using Google Drive from GAE is explained in this [article](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python).

Answer (score 0):

See [Retrieving Authenticated Google Data Feeds with Google App Engine (Python)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/python/retrieving_gdata_feeds) if you need to access the spreadsheet content.

The samples in this article is using Google Document List API but it could be easily adapted to use spreadsheets [scope](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20) and spreadsheet [client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/gdata/spreadsheets/client.py) or [service](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/gdata/spreadsheet/service.py).

If you only need to list the files, I would recommend using Drive like @SebastionKreft suggested